# Can't install Python package hdt via pip install. It gets an error: command failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, pip

I need to install a Python package on Windows 10. Python version is 3.7.
The package I need is kbqa_cq: http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/kbqa.html
I install it as doc says:

```
python -m deeppavlov install kbqa_cq
```

One of this package dependencies is [hdt](https://pypi.org/project/hdt/).
While installing hdt it gets an error:

```
BitSequence.cpp
hdt-cpp-1.3.3/libcds/include/libcdsBasics.h(27): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory,
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

As you see the error goes from C++ file.

There are some MS Build Tools installed, specifically:

- MSVC 140 build tool C++ VS 2015 (ver 14.00)
- MSVC 141 build tool C++ VS 2017 (ver 14.16)
- SDK for Windows 10 (10.0.18362)

There is no .whl for the package hdt on https://pypi.org/. Moreover the github repository of hdt is archived so it will be no help from there.
I understand that smth in MS Build Tools is missed but I've no idea what. What is a proper way to fix the error?